# How to get max() of integer value from a varchar field in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
rf_id  rf_name  
12      12
13      13
14      14
15      15
16      GF
17      BASE
```

I want to get **15** from column `rf_name` in Codeigniter. each time I should get `max('rf_name')` where characters not allowed

Comment: Presumably you are using PHP here, and, if so, then you should include your relevant code.  It isn't clear exactly what kind of answer you want here.

Comment: you can use max() on integer column.

Comment: Do you want to get maximum column value from `rf_name`?

Comment: @DanishAli yes, when using max() i'm getting 'GF' as answer but i need 15.

Comment: Are you using codeigniter ?

Comment: yes i'm using codeigniter

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at this already discussed question [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705687/how-to-get-max-value-of-numeric-values-in-varchar-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure column `rf_name` data type should be integer/float, not varchar/string/text etc.

So, according to the data type of the column, it will not store any string value

```
$maxid = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(rf_name) AS maxid FROM table')->row()->maxid;
```

OR

```
$this->db->select_max('rf_name');
$query = $this->db->get('table');
```

If you have both string and numeric values you have to do the following steps

1. Get all values of column

   ```
   $this->db->select('rf_name');
   $this-db->from('table');
   $values = $this->db->get('table')->result_array();
   ```
2. Get only values from an array

   ```
   $only_values= array();
   foreach($values as $value){
      if (is_numeric($value['rf_name'])) {
         array_push($only_values, $value['rf_name']);
      }
   }
   ```
3. use `max()` and pass the array of values to get maximum numeric value from it.

   ```
   $max_value = max($only_values);
   ```

Comment: it's not working, and datatype of column is varchar, bcz it should store both integer and character values

Comment: Then you can't use `MAX()` on it.

Comment: let me give you an alternative way.

Comment: @starlet in the `foreach` loop I've done some changes. Now `$only_values` array will have only numeric values. Try it again

Comment: I can't because i don't have much reputations to upvote

Answer (score 1):

MySql query bellow:

```
SELECT Max(CAST(rf_name as SIGNED)) as MAX_INT FROM table_name;
```

In Codeigniter:

```
$sql = "SELECT Max(CAST(rf_name as SIGNED)) as MAX_INT FROM table_name"; 
$this->db->query($sql);
```